# Accessing ADFS from outside corporate network

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, adfs3.0

I'm trying to authenticate a SPA against an active directory.

My understand till now is: 
-  using ADFS as an STS for getting tokens
- using ADAL.js for simplifying communication with ADFS

In order to setup a prove of concept, I created a virtual machine on Azure based on windows server 2016. Then installed an AD and an ADFS.

ADFS works correctly when I am on the virtual machine, I can see its metadata url on https.

Now I would like to develop my SPA from my development machine, but I cannot reach the ADFS endpoint from outside Azure.
The question is: is it correct/allowed trying to authenticate from a computer outside that network?

I read many possibilities without finding a solution: 
- using an express route for establishing a VPN
- using an ADFS proxy
- joining the AAD

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely - I do it all the time.

No - you don't need Express Route / Proxy.

In your VM configuration in Azure under "Overview", are you using the DNS name you see there.

Under "Networking", have you enabled http and https?

Comment: Thank you! So I found the problem: DNS: OK, Networking OK, IIS: KO. I did not enabled https binding on default website. On the VM, https ADFS endpoint was enough, but from outside I needed IIS set up correctly.